# How to store three-dimesional array successively (coherently) in the memory in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first experience using SO. Sorry for my English but I'll try to do my best and to describe my problem with my university task completely for your better understanding. I am sure my problem is more code and array related and not to math.

I am solving numerically 3D wave problem in the cube with using MPI, OpenMP and big dimensions and mesh sizes. Now I am writing a code to execute it on our university supercomputers.

So some little explanations and formulas to understand the problem better:

1. I have the cube with N+1 points on each axis (with numbers from ***0*** to ***N***)
2. Let me have ***s*** = **MPI_size** total number of processes with ranks from ***0*** to ***s-1***
3. I am doing ***s*** parallel areas making slices perpendicularly to Y axis (with fixed *j* numbers). I mean index *i* corresponds to x axis, j to Y and k to Z as usual.
4. So now each process with rank from 0 to s-1 is responsible for ***p=(N+1)/s*** points on my Y axis: from ***rank*p*** to ***rank*p+p-1***
5. Now I have a problem with creating three arrays with sizes **[N+1][p][N+1]**. Three because on each step of computations I use values from previous time step and from "double previous (previous of previos)" (sorry, I don't know how to say it right :) )

I tried to do it simply like:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N_p+1; i++) {
      u[i] = new double*[N_p+1];
      u_prev[i] = new double*[N_p+1];
      u_prev_prev[i] = new double*[N_p+1];

      for(int j = 0; j < N_p+1; j++) {
          u[i][j] = new double[N_p+1];
          u_prev[i][j] = new double[N_p+1];
          u_prev_prev[i][j] = new double[N_p+1];

          for(int k = 0; k < N_p+1; k++) { 
              u[i][j][k] = 0.0;
              u_prev[i][j][k] = 0.0;
              u_prev_prev[i][j][k] = 0.0;
          }
      }
}
```

But my friend who already did this task told that I will have problems when I need to send or recieve messages to/from other processes (because I need to send complete layers with size **(N+1)^2** which are perpendicular to Y axis. And with such placing of arrays in memory it would be a big problem.

Also we don't need all **N+1** points on Y axis as I did firstly, just **p** of them is ok for each process. Because memory problem is very actual (maximal **N** in some tests will be around 1536. And we are given very little resources for testing)

So he proposed to do so: (he made parallel slices perpendicular to X axis, not to Y axis as me and numeration from **0** to **N-1** and not from **0** to **N** as me, that's not a big problem. But this code is some kind of magic for me and I don't understand it totally anyway.)

```
float* buffer = new float[N * N * (N/s) * 3];
float ***u;

for (int i = left; i < right; ++i) { 
  u[i] = new float*[N]; 
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) { 
    u[i][j] = buffer + (i - left)*N*N + j*N; 
  } 
}
```

So I am try to do smth analogical while my brain is on fire and will explode soon:

```
float* buffer = new float[(N+1) * p * (N+1) * 3];
float ***u;

for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
u[i] = new float*[p];
//p = right-left+1
  for (int j = left; j <= right; ++j) {
    u[i][j] = buffer + ???; //SOS
  }
 }
```

Can please somebody try to understand such method and explain what to place instead of "???". Or any other better solution.

Also my teammate told that it would be possible to simply write *u[i][j][k]* in the code however I am not sure whether I will have **k** index with such definiton and whether I need to change all my computations syntax or not.

Sorry for such big explanation and problem. I really wan't to understand it by myself and to solve it soon. But for now i am stuck.

Also pasting a small image of cube and marked layers with red color in it for some simple vizualization.

[image: the cube with 2 pictured layers that i will need to send just for example]

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: In the second code you posted, u doesn't have enough "levels" (not sure how else to say). It should be: <code>float ***u; u = new float**[N + 1]; </code> etc.

Comment: For access to your single dimensional array, assume your sizes are x = 2, y = 2, and z = 2. Access becomes: [(i * y * z) + (j * y) + k].

Comment: Thank you for your help, guys! I succesfully stored my 3d array as one dimensional. Just needed some more patience with counting right indexes.

Comment: `i = z * width * height + y * width + x;` That `[f][o][o]` syntax is evil and should only be used in jagged arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer encapsulate this kind of problems in classes (OOP right?). It's easier to understand, reusable and with a very little overhead. A 3D matrix of any type would be:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    int _dimX, _dimY, _dimZ;
    T *_storage;
public:
    inline Matrix(int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ) {
        _dimX = dimX; _dimY = dimY; _dimZ = dimZ;
        _storage = new T[_dimX * _dimY * _dimZ];
    }
    inline ~Matrix() { delete _storage; }
    inline T* getStorage() const { return _storage; }
    inline T &operator()(int x, int y, int z) {
        return _storage[x * _dimX * _dimY + y * _dimY + z];
    }
};
```

And using it:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int xlen = 10, ylen = 5, zlen = 2;
    // Creating matrix of doubles
    Matrix<double> matrix(xlen, ylen, zlen);

    // Filling using contiguous memory array (to export)
    double *d = matrix.getStorage();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < xlen * ylen * zlen; i++)
        *d++ = ++count; // same as d[i] = ++count;

    // Using with indexes
    cout << "matrix(1,0,0) = " << matrix(1, 0, 0) << endl; // prints 51
    matrix(1, 0, 0) = 34;
    cout << "matrix(1,0,0) = " << matrix(1, 0, 0) << endl; // prints 34
    matrix(1, 0, 0)++;
    cout << "matrix(1,0,0) = " << matrix(1, 0, 0) << endl; // prints 35

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `operator()` for indexing instead of `[...]`? It's against every C++ convention (and other languages) and looks like a normal function call.

Comment: Because operator [] can take only one argument. I didn't think a lot about it, but maybe it's possible to use operator[], but every solution that comes to my mind right now are complexer and/or slower than operator().

Comment: Ah - good point. I probably would have just used a method which returns `T&` - but it's basically the same as your operator overload. Difference is academic. :) Thanks for the code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and ideas, friends! I will give a try for yours method, WPomier.
Using OOP and yours class is really useful in solving some simple computational math problems, I understood it without any problems!

Comment: Glad to help. Could you please accept the answer and maybe upvote it?